# GridView - Removing Edit and Delete columns while exporting to Excel

Tags: asp.net, gridview, export-to-excel

Thank you for viewing my question and helping. I have a asp.net application built in C#. The application has a simple gridview. I have a button to export the gridview into excel, which works as well. However, my gridview has a edit link in column 1 and a delete button in column 2. Both if these columns export to excel as well. How do I stop these two columns from exporting? I have tried a few things:

```
GridView1.Columns.RemoveAt(0);
GridView1.Columns.RemoveAt(1);
```

and...

```
GridView1.Column(0).visible = false;
```

I did a data bind after each of these while trying, but it simply does not work. I'll post my code below, and maybe someone can help me out! Thanks!

```
 public void ExportGridToExcel(GridView grdGridView, string fileName)
            {


            Response.Clear();
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition",
            string.Format("attachment;filename={0}.xls", fileName));
            Response.Charset = "";
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls";

            StringWriter stringWrite = new StringWriter();
            HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite);
            grdGridView.RenderControl(htmlWrite);
            GridView1.Columns.RemoveAt(0);
            Response.Write(stringWrite.ToString());
            Response.End();

            GridView1.AllowPaging = false;

    }
```

The girdview has the edit feature set to true, and the delete button is a template field as below:

```
<Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Button ID="btnDelete" CommandName="Delete" runat="server"     Text="Delete" CssClass="okbutton" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this entry?');" />
            </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Have your tried iterating through the GridView Rows and hiding the column cell? See this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11078027/remove-checkboxes-while-exporting-gridview-to-excel

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to hide the individual cells in the header and data rows, like this:

```
// Hides the first column in the grid (zero-based index)
GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[0].Visible = false;

// Loop through the rows and hide the cell in the first column
for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count;i++ )
{
    GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[i];
    row.Cells[0].Visible = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
GridView1.Columns[6].Visible = false;
```

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

For Columns:

```
GridName.Columns[index].Visible = false;
```

For rows:

```
Gridname.Rows[index].Visible = false;
```