# convert CheckboxField control to true/false string gridview for excel export

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

EDIT: I want to clarify that I want to keep the checkboxes on the webpage via the gridview, however I want to convert the checkboxe controls to strings when I go to export to an excel document.

I'm exporting a gridview to excel and the gridview has a checkboxfield and I want to change it to true or false so that the export works.

I am having an issue finding the checkboxfield when I loop through my gridview. I've tried numerous posts such as [Remove Grid Boxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11078027/remove-checkboxes-while-exporting-gridview-to-excel) and [Get Gridview checkbox value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19628554/gridview-get-checkbox-checked-value)

I've gone through the debugger and checking the locals and the type seems correct. Maybe I'm not looking at the right one.

string getType = gv.Rows[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11078027/remove-checkboxes-while-exporting-gridview-to-excel).Cells[7].GetType().ToString(); says "DataControlFieldCell"...
so I guess my question is, How do I drill down to get the containingField value?

gv > Rows > Results View > [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11078027/remove-checkboxes-while-exporting-gridview-to-excel) > Cells > Results View > [7] = Type is "Controls.DataControlFieldCell.... Drill down to containingField = controls.CheckBoxField

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvCompleteReport" runat="server" DataSourceID="odsGetCompleteReport" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
    CssClass="gridview" DataKeyNames="organization, service">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Organization" DataField="organization" SortExpression="organization" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Service" DataField="service" SortExpression="service" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Category" DataField="Material Category" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Material" DataField="Material Accepted" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Acceptance CD" DataField="acceptance_ds" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="County" DataField="County" />
        <asp:CheckBoxField HeaderText="Residential" DataField="residential_fl" />
        <asp:CheckBoxField HeaderText="Commercial" DataField="commercial_fl" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Svc Type" DataField="service_type_ds" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Code Behind

```
int count = gv.Controls.Count;
        int rowCount = gv.Rows.Count;
        //Loop through the rows
        for (int i = 1; i < gv.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            int rowCellCount = gv.Rows[i].Cells.Count;
            //Loop through the cells
            for (int ci = 0; ci < rowCellCount; ci++)
            {
                //This never gets hit 
                if (gv.Rows[i].Cells[ci].GetType() == typeof(CheckBoxField))
                {
                   CheckBox cb = gv.Rows[i].Cells[ci].Controls[0] as CheckBox;
                   //Tried: Control cb = gv.Rows[i].Cells[ci].Controls[0] as CheckBox (or CheckBoxField);
                    Control currentControl = cb;
                    gv.Controls.Remove(currentControl);
                    gv.Controls.AddAt(i, new LiteralControl((currentControl as CheckBox).Checked ? "True" : "False"));

                }
                else
                {
                }

            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert that checkboxFiled into a [TemplateField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb288032.aspx)

Something like:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Residential">
<ItemTemplate>
  <asp:CheckBox ID="chbResidential" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("residential_fl") %>'></asp:CheckBox>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Then you can find the CheckBox in the code-behind:

```
CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) gv.Rows[i].FindControl("chbResidential");
```

Comment: Thanks GBS, I changed it over to what you have to see if I could grab it and change it. Still not able to remove the control and swap it out. It's showing up now as a controlCollection.

Comment: So you are getting value for "cb" correct? or is cb still null?

Comment: Printing out the value was null. In the locals, it lists it as a "controlCollection". I just made the datagrid say yes or no and exported it to Excel that way. They don't "need" the cb's. I just wanted to figure it out for learning purposes. I couldn't spend any more time on it. But thank you guys for the assistance!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your stand, you just want "True" or "False" to be written there.
Then you may use directly BoundField instead of checkboxfield. Database has True/False values stored for bit and those would be printed on page, I think.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I made an edit above to clarify the confusion. I am looking to keep the check boxes but convert the values to strings when I go to export out to an excel doc.